# Changing the behaviour of the typeof operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typeof

I would like to know if there is any way of overriding the behaviour of the `typeof` operator. Specifically, I want to return "string" when the `typeof` operator is called both on `foo = "hi"` and `bar = new String("hi")`.

`typeof bar` returns "object" but I want it to return "string".

I know this can be done by declaring my own function or accessing the constructor name but I want to modify the behaviour of `typeof` operator.

EDIT - **I am looking for some code that I can add say at the beginning of the program which modifies the behaviour of all the typeof operators in the rest of the program.**

Comment: I'm 99% sure you can't override `typeof`...just create your own function

Comment: Thought as much..just wanted to be sure..thanks!

Comment: No problem! Not sure if someone can back me up with documentation, but...

Comment: Why don't you do `typeof obj.valueOf()`? It'll return a string primitive for both.

Comment: @ian looks like typeof is an operator so don't think you can change that: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3

Comment: @HMR True, good point and good link...with http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3 as well. Nonetheless, I guess I'm looking more for something that says "operators can't be overwritten". I mean, it's obvious to us that they can't, but is there somewhere in the spec that says operators can't? Or am I overthinking this?

Comment: @Ian https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=pFIHldY_CkszsFxMkQOReAQ&gid=2 under Operator Overloading

Comment: @Ian: I'd say the [*Conformance* section](http://es5.github.io/#x2) implies this. If it would be possible to change the behaviour, the implementation would no longer be conformant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is impossible. The behaviour of native operators cannot be changed.

Related links:

- [*Why hasn't operator overloading been added to ECMAScript?*](http://www.quora.com/Why-hasnt-operator-overloading-been-added-to-ECMAScript) at quora.com
- The [ES *value proxy* proposal](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman%3avalue_proxies). It doesn't let you change the existing functionality of `typeof`, but would enable you to define your own additional types.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change a Javascript operator, however you can check if it's a string OR a string object with `instanceof`.

```
var strObj = new String('im a string')
var str = 'im a string'

alert(strObj instanceof String); //true
alert(typeof strObj == 'string'); //false
alert(str instanceof String); //false
alert(typeof str == 'string'); //true
alert(strObj instanceof String || typeof strObj == 'string'); //true
alert(str instanceof String || typeof str == 'string'); //true
```

Of course, it is much more simple and shorter to create your own function, but if you want to use native JS, that is the way : `alert(str instanceof String || typeof str == 'string');`.

Comment: The same thing happened to me. I think there's a trigger happy kid here. People should really not be allowed to downvote an answer which has no other downvotes without posting a comment explaining why they downvoted the answer.

Comment: @AaditMShah Totally agree with you. IMO, there is only 3 type of answer: Good which are upvoted; Working which are, like mine, to be upvoted if the user is kind; and wrong who deserve a downvote. As i can see, both of our answers are working...

Comment: I dont think both your answers answer the question to the point. As I said "I am looking for some code that I can add say at the beginning of the program which modifies the behaviour of all the typeof operators in the rest of the program." 
Again, I did not downvote yours either.

Comment: @everconfusedGuy, I understand, but they actually clearly answer your question (wich is no) and give a little explaination (can't change javascript operator). In addition, we add an alternative. We both know the question was answered correctly, we are just adding some true information and we are wondering why we are getting a downvote (since it's true, you know?). Anyway, the downvoter will probably never come back here so it is a lost cause!

Comment: You can change the behaviour of the `instanceof` operator (now, as this was 2013, the answer might have been true).

Answer (score 1):

typeof is an [operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) in JavaScript so I'm quite sure you can't. To detect if something is a string you could use something like this:

```
var s = "hello";
console.log(s.substr&&s.charAt&&s.toUpperCase==="".toUpperCase)//true
s = new String("hello");
console.log(s.substr&&s.charAt&&s.toUpperCase==="".toUpperCase)//true
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't modify the behavior of `typeof` or any other operator for that matter. However the next best solution is to use `Object.prototype.toString` as follows:

```
function typeOf(value) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(value).slice(8, -1);
}
```

Now you can use it as follows (see the demo - http://jsfiddle.net/CMwdL/):

```
var foo = "hi";
var bar = new String("hi");

alert(typeOf(foo)); // String
alert(typeOf(bar)); // String
```

The reason this works is given in the following link: http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#types.typeof

Comment: I knew how to get around this if i was can declare my own function (as mentioned in my question). I just wanted to know if I could modify the behaviour of the typeof operator itself

Comment: @naini No, you can't modify the behavior of `typeof`. However my answer is the best solution there is. I know that for a fact. Period.