# Javascript change Typeof

Tags: javascript

I am new in JavaScript.

My code allows me to list the elements of a JSON document as well as their types, and concatenate all its in a string **donnees_types**.

The problem is that the typeof in JavaScript returns only number for a number and string for a string. I want to return double instead of number and varchar instead of string in order to get:

temperature double, humidite double, built varchar, fire varchar

I know I can replace in my string using replace, but is there any other method to change the typeof?

```js
 var event = {
  "temperature" : 12.45,
  "humidite" : 45.78,
  "built" : "charone",
  "fire" : "chartwo",
  "topic" : "sk1_001/data"
 };
 
var keys = Object.keys(event);

donnees_types = "";
 
for(var i= 0; i < keys.length -1; i++)
donnees_types +=  keys[i] + " " +  typeof(event[keys[i]]) + ", ";

var donnees_t = donnees_types.substring(0, donnees_types.length - 2);
console.log(donnees_t);
```

Comment: No, you can't change the behavior of  `typeof`. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333761/changing-the-behaviour-of-the-typeof-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a type `double`. `typeof parseFloat("2.33"); // "number"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the behaviour of the typeof operator in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333761/changing-the-behaviour-of-the-typeof-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have primitive types other than [Boolean, Number, and String (well, technically Null, Undefined, and Symbol too)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures). You would need to create your own mapping between the JavaScript types and what you need.

Comment: Thank you Mike :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't change `typeof`. You could write your own function to map to the outputs you want.

```js
function typeLabel(o){
  switch(typeof(o)){
    case "number" :
      return "double";
    case "string":
      return "varchar";
    default : 
      return typeof(o);
  }
}
var event = {
  "temperature" : 12.45,
  "humidite" : 45.78,
  "built" : "charonea",
  "fire" : "chartwo",
  "topic" : "sk1_001/data"
 };
 
var keys = Object.keys(event);

donnees_types = "";
 
for(var i= 0; i < keys.length -1; i++)
donnees_types +=  keys[i] + " " +  typeLabel(event[keys[i]]) + ", ";

var donnees_t = donnees_types.substring(0, donnees_types.length - 2);
console.log(donnees_t);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look below - but be aware of some artifacts of isNaN (see documentation)

```js
 var event = {
  "temperature" : 12.45,
  "humidite" : 45.78,
  "built" : "charone",
  "fire" : "chartwo",
  "topic" : "sk1_001/data"
 };
 
var keys = Object.keys(event);

donnees_types = "";
 
for(var i= 0; i < keys.length -1; i++)
donnees_types +=  keys[i] + " " +  (isNaN(event[keys[i]])?'varchar':'double') + ", ";

var donnees_t = donnees_types.substring(0, donnees_types.length - 2);
console.log(donnees_t);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get the functionality that you want by doing some additional a work to further classify the value based on what `typeof` returns and some custom logic, but you cannot change the functionality of `typeof` itself.

**Pseudocode:**

```
if `typeof` foo is `number`
    if `<insert integer rules here>`
        then foo is an integer
    else if `<insert float rules here>`
        then foo is a float
    else if . . .
```

The reason why you are running into this is that JavaScript is a "loosely typed" language . . . it does not recognize data types at a detailed level, but rather groups them into broader categories.  These categories are the basis for the values that `typeof` returns.

You can read more about `typeof` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) and JavaScript typing [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures), for a quick list of what you can expect, here are the values that `typeof` will return to you:

```
Type                                           Result

Undefined                                      "undefined"
Null                                           "object"
Boolean                                        "boolean"
Number                                         "number"
String                                         "string"
Symbol                                         "symbol"
Host object (provided by the JS environment)   Implementation-dependent
Function object                                "function"
Any other object                               "object"
```